# Outlook, Assign a Category to a message based on string in attachment

Tags: vba, search, outlook

In Outlook, I want to assign a category to messages received from a specific sender with an attachment that contains the word "Error".

Searching for these messages is very easy. I would simply set a rule if outlook rules were a little bit more flexible. None of the macro examples that I've seen search the contents of the file attached.

Here is the search string that works for me:

```
attachment:Error from:example@email.edu
```

I just want something that will assign `.Categories = "Error"` to items that meet the criteria

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for searching inside attachments. You can find all the items from a specific sender and attachment. Then you can iterate over these items and check attachments whether they contain a keyword or not. Only then you can make a decision to set a category or not.

Comment: The universal search bar in outlook is capable of checking the contents of attachments for a specific key word. Is there no way use that functionality in a macro?